# Executable JAR file also contains the source code

Tags: java, jar

I know this question asked many times but I can't find my answer from older question  .I have four packages an I want to create jar file from this packages my main program is in main package  . I use this statement like so  :

```
jar -cvfm app.jar manifest.txt *
```

When I saw the content of a jar file my sources (`.java`) also exist in the jar file but I want just to have `.class` file in my `jar` file  .How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `*.class` instead of `*`?

Comment: yes but it didn't work also

Comment: Can you also post the output that comes while you build? Should be something like adding: Main.Class etc

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your mean

Comment: Just open the jar in Winzip or 7Zip and delete those java files. Still your jar will work.

Comment: @Pasupathi tnx alot it works

Comment: You could compile the class files to a different directory (`-d` I think)

Comment: This one also worked

`jar -cvfm App.jar manifest.txt com\*.class org\*.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change the command to:

`jar -cvfm app.jar manifest.txt *.class`

You missed the `.class` part. By using the wildcard `*` you've included everything.

Good Luck.

Comment: This is not working when I have 2 different packages in a directory.

Comment: @Pasupathi You are right, but your case is not analogous to the main question which I've answered.

Comment: The question is talking about four packages. If my view is correct, that is the challenge here not creating jar out of classes. That's pretty simple. Isn't?